# Python - Numpy array index as tuple

Tags: python, numpy

If we create an array with Numpy , we can use many functionalities given by numpy library.

For example if `c` is a matrix

```
print(c[:,1])
```

will print every value in the column 1.

Now, when i index the c matrix in this way, am i indexing using a tuple ? If yes, how is possible to have a tuple with ':' inside ?

Comment: Are you asking how slicing works or how to have the ':' character in a tuple?

Comment: `print(c[EMPTY:EMPTY,1])` is better understood.

Comment: @doctorlove: I think Tantaros wants to understand how Numpy processes such slices internally.

Answer (score 2):

The colon syntax is syntactical sugar for a `slice(..)` object. Your expression is equvalent to:

```
#        v slice object
print(c[(slice(None), 1)])
#       ^   tuple      ^
```

So you have passed a tuple containing a `slice(None)` object as first element, and `1` as second element.

The mapping of slice syntax to `slice(..)` objects is as follows:

1. the colon `:` is equivalent to `slice(None)`;
2. if it is `:b`, then it is equivalent to `slice(b)`;
3. `a:` is equivalent to `slice(a, None)`;
4. `a:b` is equivalent to `slice(a, b)`;
5. `::c` is equivalent to `slice(None, None, c)`;
6. `:b:c` to `slice(None, b, c)`;
7. `a::c` is equivalent to `slice(a, None, c)`; and
8. `a:b:c` to `slice(a, b, c)`.

Note that slice syntax is only supported in the context of an itemgetter (so `x[..]`).